# Какой тип параметра String принимает класс AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>

Tags: java, android

В поле `editText` ввожу 1000, передаю в `GetString` , при проверки 
`if(test.equals(params))` всегда получается `false`.
На скриншоте видно что переменная `test` и `params` равны 1000. Как это понимать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_string);

}

public void onClick(View view) {
    GetString getString = new GetString();
    getString.execute(editText.getText().toString());
}


class GetString extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String test = "1000";
        if (test.equals(params)) {
            Log.d("MyLog", "YES");
        } else {
            Log.d("MyLog", "NO");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Это в idea такая тема или какой то другой редактор?

Comment: Android Studio + plugin Material Design, тему для подсветки кода сам сделал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

params - это не одиночный String, а массив String'ов.

Используйте в сравнении

```
test.equals(params[0])
```

[Почитайте про varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)